# How to fill the bigger square with smaller squares effectively?

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix, mathematical-optimization

I need to write in python3 a function that fills the bigger square with smaller squares basing on the input.

The input is a list of positive integers. Each integer is the number of squares per row. So the list [3, 8, 5, 2] means I got 4 rows of squares where first one has 3 squares, second one 8 and so on. All squares in all rows are of the same size.

The output should be description of rows distribution in the form of list of lists.

The thing is that on the output there can not be empty rows. So effectively the number of columns can not be greater than the number of rows. The rows can be split though into two or more rows. So for example for the list [3, 8, 5, 2] the function should return [[3], [5, 3], [5], [2]]:

```
AAA
BBBBB
BBB
CCCCC
DD
```

and for input [14,13,2,12] it should return [[7,7], [7,6], [2], [7,5]]:

```
AAAAAAA
AAAAAAA
BBBBBBB
BBBBBB
CC
DDDDDDD
DDDDD
```

As we can see, the number of rows and columns is in both examples equal. Of course it's not always possible but the lesser difference between the number of columns and rows, the more efficient the algorythm is - the better the square is filled. In general we aim to get as many columns as possible and as little rows as possible.

And here is the issue - the above examples used 4 input rows - the input list can have a lot of more elements (for example 200 input rows). And the problem is to find optimial way to split the rows (for example if i should split 18 as 9+9 or 6+6+6 or 7+7+4 or maybe 5+5+5+3). Because every time i split the rows basing on available columns (that depend on the number of used rows), I get more output rows and therefore I am able to use more additional available columns - and I fall into some weird loop or recursion.

I'm sorry if there is some easy solution that I don't see and thank you in advance for help <3

EDIT: Here I include example function that simply ignores the fact that the number of rows increases and just treats the number of input rows as maximum amount of columns possible:

```
def getSquare(x):
    output = list()
    ln = len(x)
    for i in x:
        if i <= ln:
            output.append([i])
        else:
            split = list()
            nrows = i // ln
            for j in range(nrows):
                split.append(ln)
            if i % ln:
                split.append(i % ln)
            output.append(split)
    return output

print(getSquare([14, 13, 2, 12]))
# returns [[4, 4, 4, 2], [4, 4, 4, 1], [2], [4, 4, 4]]
# so 4 columns and 12 rows 
# columns - maximum number in the matrix
# rows - number of all elements in the matrix (length of flattened output)
# while it should return: [[7,7], [7,6], [2], [7,5]]
# so 7 columns and 7 rows 
#(nr of columns should be not larger but as close to the number of rows as possible)
```

EDIT2: It doesn't have to return perfect square - just something as close to square as possible - for example for [4,3,3] it should return [[3,1],[3]
,[3]] while for extreme cases like [1,1,1] it should just return [[1],[1],[1]]

Comment: Try to provide the code you used to overcome the problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is this like [line breaking](https://xxyxyz.org/line-breaking/)?

Comment: Kind of - with the exception that we aim to make a square - so the length of the line depends on the number of lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have improved an answer, adding some stop signs to generally speed up the algorithm. It also gives much more efficient answer when no ideal solution was found.

```py
arr = [14, 13, 2, 12]  # as close to a square as possible 

def getSquare(lst):
    output = []
    mx = max(lst)
    for cols in range(min(len(lst), mx), mx + 1):
        out = []
        rows = 0
        for j in lst:
            ln = j // cols
            r = j % cols
            out.append([cols] * ln)
            rows += ln
            if r:
                out[-1].append(r)
                rows += 1
        if rows >= cols:
            output = out
        else:
            break
    return output

for i in getSquare(arr):
    for j in i:
        print("*" * j)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list = [3, 8, 5, 2] #As close to a Square as possible

def getSquare(list):
    
    for i in range(1, max(list)+1):

        output = []
        num = 0

        for j in list:

            output.append([i]*(j//i))

            num += j//i

            if j%i != 0:

                output[-1].append(j%i)

                num += 1

        if num == i:

            return output

    i = int( sum(list) ** (1/2) // 1)

    output = []
    
    for j in list:

        output.append([i]*(j//i))

        num += j//i

        if j%i != 0:

            output[-1].append(j%i)

            num += 1

    return output

for i in getSquare(list):

    for j in i:

        print("*"*j)
```

Here I just repeat the splitting process of the list until `i` and `num` become same.

Comment: for input 
list = [2, 30, 40, 50]
it returns "None"
Also the depth of the output is 3 (list of lists of lists) not list of lists.
The i and num doesn't have to be the same just as close as possible - for example it's impossible for input [1, 1, 1, 1] to achieve same number of rows and columns

Comment: for [2, 30, 40, 50], it gives an error because it is not possible to make a square with it that has the same number of rows and columns @AmaeSaeki

Comment: As I specified - it doesn't have to. It just should be as close as possible - so when 8 rows and 8 columns isn't possible, maybe 8 rows and 7 columns is

Comment: It should just return most efficient solution found

Comment: could you please give me an example that is not working in my code, but should have a solution

Comment: Every input should have a solution. Just reverse the range and replace `num == i` with `num >= i`.

Comment: Your code seems to make the square nicely. The thing is that the purpose of this function isn't checking if making a square is possible. The purpose of this function is to always get some distribution - if it's not possible to achieve perfect square, it should return something as close as possible - so for input [4, 3, 3] it should return [[3, 1], [3], [3]] -> 4 rows and 3 columns. In extreme cases like input [1, 1, 1] it should just return [[1], [1], [1]]

Comment: I just tested, with >= sign for [4, 3, 3] it returns [[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]] instead of [[3, 1], [3], [3]]

Comment: @AmaeSaeki, I changed the code so that it gives the approx. answer incase of no solution

Comment: @KillerRebooted
After first tests it works amazing, thank you! Does it have large complexity?

Comment: It is quite time consuming the numbers are absurdly big, but at the same time it won't be able to visualise a square if the numbers are tooo big. It is preferrable to have only small numbers (below 100)

Comment: I found an issue - for input [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 8] it returns [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [4, 4]] (4x10) instead of [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [8]] (9x8)

Comment: I posted an answer with the improved version of your code

Comment: for the input [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 8], Imo if the output is [4,4], it resembles more of a square than just [8], but ofc it depends upon opinion.
The problem is the lists with 1 in it. because from my tests, only the cases with 1 are appearing to generate problems, what if incase of a list like this, we could just split it as [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]]

Comment: if 1 cause issues, 2 will likely too - just you need larger numbers or more numbers - you could try something like [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 16] -> twice more numbers and twice bigger numbers

Comment: Anyways your code and mine - they both have large complexity - practically O(rows * columns). I wonder if that could be done better - cause this algorythm is kind of brutal - try all possible column lengths until you manage to equalize the rows and colums. For small numbers it's enough and for my needs also :) But from perspective of programming perfection it's ineffective anyways! *laughs*  Fas in his answer metioned some algorythm with log complexity but not sure i understood him well

Answer (score 0):

Essentially when you decrease width, you increase number of rows (vice versa is also true: when you increase width, you decrease number of rows), that's why you want to as far as it's possible equalise width and height, because that would get you minimum area of covering square. From this point of view your problem looks like [ternary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_search): minimize maximum of resulting width and height.

So we perform ternary search over width (fix it) and calculate resulting maximum side of square. Calculating function is pretty obvious:

```py
def get_max_side(l, fixed_width):  # O(len(l))
  height = 0
  for i in l:
    height += i // fixed_width
    if i % fixed_width:
      height += 1
  return max(fixed_width, height)
```

Then use it in a ternary search algorithm to find minimum of `get_max_side` and restore the answer using found value. Time complexity is `O(len(l) * log(max_meaningful_square_width))`.